# CSS inner id selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got below id selectors in a CSS file. Headerphoto and logo-box are inner id-selectors of header id. Do I really need to add those two as inner id-selectors? I can add them as just normal id selectors. What is the best way of doing this? What are the pros and cons?

Thank you!

```
/* Header styles */
#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 176px;
    text-align: left;       
    margin: 0; padding: 0;  
    background: #FFF;
}

#header #headerphoto {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px ; top: 15px;
    width: 455px;
    height: 156px;
    background: #FFF url(headerphoto.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#header #logo-box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px ; top: 15px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 156px;  
    background:#1c1e27;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter as long as only one of `#headerphoto` and `#logo-box` exist on each page and you're sure the structure for these three elements will be the same.

It only **really** matters to add the `#header` ID if, on some pages, `#headerphoto` and `#logo-box` appear in elements that don't have `id="header"`, your stylesheet is used by all these pages, and you want the styles to apply if and only if these elements are in that one. But in such a case, that'd make your page structure rather inconsistent, wouldn't it?

Regarding performance, whether it's faster, slower or the same to nest ID selectors, I don't care, and neither should you, the stylesheet author, since **ID selectors are already *the fastest* anyway**.

Comment: Then again, sometimes I add the outer ID selectors just to logically group these elements together in my stylesheet. For example, these elements are found within `#header` so they're somewhat related. Adding the `#header` selector visually indicates this relation. So in a way, the code documents itself. Now, I really could use comments instead, but seriously, I don't care.

Comment: Thanks :-) What is your opinion on below "Jochen Hilgers" answer?

Comment: @CharithJ: Not so sure about that.

Comment: Anyway, I decided to keep them as it is because that group them logically as you also mentioned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to add the #header selector, but i've heard the page rendering is faster the more precise the selector was declared. In my opinion it doesn't matter.