# Using CSS, does it make sense to select with multiple ID attributes "#id1 #id2 {..."

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS inner id selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633394/css-inner-id-selectors)

I encountered the following CSS selector and I feel that it doesn't quite make sense.

```
#id1 #id2 .class1 {
 color: #fff;
}
```

It seems to me that the CSS selector would match first to the element `#id1`, and then to the element `#id2`, and then to elements beneath and including `#id2` that have a class attribute set to `class1`.

My hunch is that it is valid CSS, but also that it is unnecessary to specify `#id1`, or that if it is meant only to match a document when `#id1` has a child `#id2`, but not to match an `#id2` without a parent `#id1`.

Since `#id1` has a specificity of 0,1,0,0 and `#id2` has a specificity of 0,1,0,0, and `.class1` has a specificity of 0,0,1,0, you get 0,2,1,0. But is this necessary or useful? It seems like a more efficient method would be to create two rules and select by each id separately.

I can't seem to find any other examples of a CSS selector that looks like `#id1 #id2 ...`.

Can anyone comment on this and help give me a sanity check?

Comment: Your hunch is right. Nesting ID selectors can filter away elements of certain IDs under certain documents while applying styles to other documents. It's all about the specificity.

Comment: read this article may be that's help you to how to define thing in css https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS

Comment: Thank you, @BoltClock. The scenarios are similar. Thanks everyone for commenting. In my case, I'm just worried that there is a more sensible way to do the layout such that you don't need to select for an `#id2` in an `#id1`... maybe that would be some dynamic layout, but to me in would be more sensible to select a more direct route to the desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

This selects elements with the class `class1` and an ancestor (including parents) with id `id2` which itself has an ancestor with `id1`. So your interpretation was close, but this won't select an element with `id2` and `class1` unless it is contained within another `id2`.

If you wanted it to be including `id2` you would have to use `#id1 #id2.class1, #id1 #id2 .class1` as the selector.

If you just did `#id2 .class1` then you would select elements with class `class1` inside an element with `id2` regardless of whether or not the `id2` element is in an `id1`.

So the two selectors have different meanings.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. So, I understand that the CSS syntax is valid, and that it will select for `#id2` only within an `#id1`, but I'm not sure that it makes sense as a developer to select that way when it seems to me there would be a slightly more efficient layout. Think efficiency, sensible layout. Right?

Comment: @Anonymous It hardly has an impact on efficiency but it can make a real difference to the page since they have different meanings. Consider a stylesheet that is shared over 10 different pages, where all 10 pages have '#id2' with '.class1` elements within them. But the `#id2` is only wrapped in an `#id1` on one of the pages. Then this style will only apply to one page, not all 10, which could be desired behavior.